# How to use filter item in pjax in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, pjax

I use Laravel and code is:

```
<div class="card-body">
     @php($explodeFilter = [])
     @if(request()->get('filterItem') != null)
         @php($explodeFilter = explode(',', implode(request()->get('filterItem'))))
     @endif
     @foreach($filterItems as $item)
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkFilter" @if(array_search($item->id, $explodeFilter)) checked @endif name="filter_item" value="{{ $item->id }}" id="{{ $item->id }}">
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</label>
         </div>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

Url is:

```
/category/tv?page=1&filterItem[]=16,17,18
```

But result in blade is:

```
| url      | result           |
| -------- | --------------   |
| 16       | checked is false |
| 17       | checked is true  |
| 18       | checked is true  |
```

How to issue this problem
and write more concisely?

Comment: how about URL:```/category/tv?page=1&&filterItem=[16,17,18]``` ??